# How to set rectangle split with the same size (especially the width)？

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-styles

I'm using rectangle split to draw link nodes:

[image]
[image]

How to ensure every rectangle split with the same size, especially with the same width! no matter it is empty or with one digit or with two digits (maximum two digits, or like "-1")

MWE(my code):

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{memorygraphs}
\tikzset{
    phead/.style={
           rectangle, draw, text height=3mm, text width=3mm,
       text centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
            draw,
            %text height=height("I"),
            %text depth=depth("I"),
            anchor=mid,
            %inner sep=0pt,
            %minimum width=0.6cm,
            every block,
    },
    arity/.style={
        block,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1+1,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split every empty part={},
        rectangle split empty part width=0.6cm,
        minimum size=0.6cm,
    }   
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[memory graph]

\node[phead, label=above:head] (head) {};

\def\prevname{head}
\foreach \name/\labela/\val in {1/7/,2/7/,3//,4/12/,5/13/,6/0/-1}{
    \ifnum \name=1
        \node[block,arity=1,right=of \prevname] (a\name) {\labela};
        \draw[ref] (\prevname.center) -- (a\name);
    \else
        \node[block,arity=1,right=of \prevname.arg 1 east] (a\name) {\labela};
        \draw[ref] (\prevname.arg 1 center) -- (a\name);
    \fi
    
    
    \xdef\prevname{a\name}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see I've override some tikz style of the memorygraphics in the code above, like `block` and `arity`

Some code(style) of package `memeorygraphics`: https://ctan.org/pkg/memorygraphs

```tex
\tikzset{
    memory graph/.style={
        node distance=1.5em,
    },
    every block/.style={},
    block/.style={
        draw,
        text height=height("I"),
        text depth=depth("I"),
        anchor=mid,
        every block,
    },
    block/.append code={%
        \let\arg\memorygraphs@arg%
        \gdef\memorygraphs@arity{0}%
    },
    block mark north east/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \pgfinterruptpath
                \draw[#1]
                    ($(\tikzlastnode.head north east)-(\ifnum\memorygraphs@arity=0 .5\pgflinewidth\else0\fi,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- +(0,-\memorygraphs@marklength)
                    -- ($(\tikzlastnode.head north east)-(\ifnum\memorygraphs@arity=0 .5\pgflinewidth\else0\fi+\memorygraphs@marklength,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- cycle;
                \endpgfinterruptpath
            \endpgfextra
        },
    },
    block mark south east/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \pgfinterruptpath
                \draw[#1]
                    ($(\tikzlastnode.head south east)+(\ifnum\memorygraphs@arity=0 -.5\pgflinewidth\else0\fi,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- +(0,\memorygraphs@marklength)
                    -- ($(\tikzlastnode.head south east)+(\ifnum\memorygraphs@arity=0 -.5\pgflinewidth\else0\fi-\memorygraphs@marklength,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- cycle;
                \endpgfinterruptpath
            \endpgfextra
        },
    },
    block mark north west/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \pgfinterruptpath
                \draw[#1]
                    ($(\tikzlastnode.head north west)+(.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- +(0,-\memorygraphs@marklength)
                    -- ($(\tikzlastnode.head north west)-(-.5\pgflinewidth-\memorygraphs@marklength,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- cycle;
                \endpgfinterruptpath
            \endpgfextra
        },
    },
    block mark south west/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \pgfinterruptpath
                \draw[#1]
                    ($(\tikzlastnode.head south west)+(.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- +(0,\memorygraphs@marklength)
                    -- ($(\tikzlastnode.head south west)+(.5\pgflinewidth+\memorygraphs@marklength,.5\pgflinewidth)$)
                    -- cycle;
                \endpgfinterruptpath
            \endpgfextra
        },
    },
    arity/.style={
        block,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1+1,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split every empty part={},
        rectangle split empty part width=.2em,
    },
    arity/.append code={%
        \pgfmathsetcount\c@pgf@counta{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle split parts}}%
        \ifnum\c@pgf@counta=0\else\advance\c@pgf@counta by-1 \fi
        \xdef\memorygraphs@arity{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
    },
  ref/.style={
        {Circle[length=3pt]}-Latex,
        shorten <=-1.5pt,
        rounded corners=.2em,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small variation of nice @Peter Grill answer (+1) with pure `tikz`, i.e.: without `memorygraphs` package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}

\newlength\MinimumWidth
\setlength{\MinimumWidth}{\widthof{00}}
\tikzset{
arr/.style={{Circle[length=2pt 4, sep=0pt -4]}-Stealth},
arity/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1+1,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        minimum height=10pt,
        rectangle split empty part width=\MinimumWidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        text width=\MinimumWidth, align=center,
        execute at end node=\vphantom{fg},
        draw,
        on chain},
box/.style = {draw, text width=#1, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0pt},
box/.default = 4mm
        }
        
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 7mm,
  start chain = on chain,
                        ]
\node[arity=0, box, label=head] (a0) {};
\foreach \labela/\val [count=\i from 0, count=\j] in {7/,7/,/,12/,13/,0/}%
{
\node[arity=1] (a\j) {\labela};
\draw[arr] (a\i.two north |- a\i.east) -- (a\j);
}

\node[arity=0, box, label=head,
      below=of a0] (b0) {};
\foreach \labela/\val [count=\i from 0, count=\j] in {17/,27/,/,2/,3/,0/}%
{
\node[arity=1] (b\j) {\labela};
\draw[arr] (b\i.two north |- b\i.east) -- (b\j);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Removed are colors of nodes borders, now all nodes' parts has equal width and height.

Comment: Thanks! beautiful solution! Could you please give a demo of vertical rectangle split? like this: ![](https://img-blog.csdnimg.cn/5f49b5265aa4449da76582c835aef7e9.png)

Comment: If you have new problem, please ask new question. In principle you need in my answer remove  code line `rectangle split horizontal`, and accordingly draw arrows.

Comment: ```tex
arityv/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1+1,
        rectangle split every empty part={},
        rectangle split empty part height=height("I"),
        minimum height=6mm,
        text height=height("I"),
        text width=\MinimumWidth, align=center,% <--- NOTE
        draw,
        on chain},
box/.style = {draw, text width=#1, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0pt},
box/.default = 4mm
        }
```

Comment: I've open a new issue, please have a look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638146/how-to-set-rectangle-split-with-the-same-size-width-and-height

Comment: Another question: How to modify the node distance between `b2` and `b3`? (and others distance remain unchanged)

Comment: @xaero, locally set desired distance. That means, that nodes should not be in loop anymore.

Comment: According to the TiKZ manual, can `node pre sep=<length>` or `node post sep` satisfy it？But I don't know how to use the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Define a length of the width you desire. Here I set it to the width of two digits `00`:

```
\newlength\MinimumWidth
\setlength{\MinimumWidth}{\widthof{00}}
```

and then apply

```
text width=\MinimumWidth, align=center,
```

The two different widths of the text yield same width rectangles:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{memorygraphs}
\usepackage{calc}

\pagecolor{white}

\newlength\MinimumWidth
\setlength{\MinimumWidth}{\widthof{00}}
\tikzset{
    phead/.style={
           rectangle, draw, text height=3mm, text width=3mm,
       text centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
            draw,
            %text height=height("I"),
            %text depth=depth("I"),
            anchor=mid,
            %inner sep=0pt,
            %minimum width=0.6cm,
            every block,
    },
    arity/.style={
        block,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1+1,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split every empty part={},
        rectangle split empty part width=0.6cm,
        minimum height=0.6cm,
        text width=\MinimumWidth, align=center,% <--- NOTE
    }   
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[memory graph]

\node[phead, label=above:head] (head) {};

\def\prevname{head}
\foreach \name/\labela/\val in {1/7/,2/7/,3//,4/12/,5/13/,6/0/-1}{
    \ifnum \name=1
        \node[block,arity=1,right=of \prevname, red] (a\name) {\labela};
        \draw[ref] (\prevname.center) -- (a\name);
    \else
        \node[block,arity=1,right=of \prevname.arg 1 east, blue] (a\name) {\labela};
        \draw[ref] (\prevname.arg 1 center) -- (a\name);
    \fi
    \xdef\prevname{a\name}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[memory graph]

\node[phead, label=above:head] (head) {};

\def\prevname{head}
\foreach \name/\labela/\val in {1/17/,2/27/,3//,4/2/,5/3/,6/0/-1}{
    \ifnum \name=1
        \node[block,arity=1,right=of \prevname, red] (a\name) {\labela};
        \draw[ref] (\prevname.center) -- (a\name);
    \else
        \node[block,arity=1,right=of \prevname.arg 1 east, blue] (a\name) {\labela};
        \draw[ref] (\prevname.arg 1 center) -- (a\name);
    \fi
    \xdef\prevname{a\name}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Text width controls the width of box? minimum size didn't work?